# Evaluate function using assumptions

Tags: evaluation, assumptions

I know there is an option `Assumptions` for functions such as `Simplify`, `Integrate`, etc. I am trying to use assumptions also for other functions. A simplified example:

```
Sort[{a,b}]
```

yields

> {a,b}

I would like to use something like

```
Refine[Sort[{a,b}],a>b]
```

(which still produces `{a,b}`) to yield

> {b,a}

but am unable to achieve this, even when playing around with `Unevaluated`, `Hold`, etc.

I hope the example is meaningful and not too simplistic.

Comment: you need to supply `Sort` with an ordering function as a second argument. With just that example its not clear what the rule should be.

Comment: But even if I use e.g. `Sort[{a, b}, Less]`, the problem persists. The "rule" in this case is simply supposed to indicate that `b` is less than `a` and not vice versa, i.e. that it should be sorted `{b,a}`. @Kuba: I'm up for more complex solutions with potential Indeterminate results of the rules are inconsistent, but I could not achieve anything like this.

Comment: This is just not what functions like `Refine[]` and `Assuming[]` are for, hence that `Refine[TrueQ[a > b], a > b]` returns `False`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
rank = {a -> 2, b -> 1};
SortBy[{a, b}, # /. rank &]
```

> {b,a}

this will have all sorts of odd behavior unless you assign a rank to everything in the input list.

similar:

```
desiredorder = {c, b, a};
SortBy[{a, b, c, a, c}, Position[desiredorder, #] &]
```

> {c, c, b, a, a}

You might try something like this,

```
Sort[ {1, a, 0, b, 3, c} ,
 Which[
   TrueQ[ Sort[{##}] == {a, b} ], OrderedQ[Reverse@{##}],
   True, OrderedQ[{##}]] &]
```

> {0, 1, 3, b, a, c}

again many potential inconsistencies.

Comment: Thank you! But that would mean in a more complex example, I would first have to translate all my assumptions into some "rank set"? So I should rather not do what I am trying to do...? I was surprised it is such that an odd wish...

Comment: one way or another you need rules for every pair of items in the list that results in a unique ordering regardless of the order that the sort algorithm makes the comparisons.